# TeX4ht and LaTeX3 - Do they go togther?

Tags: tex4ht, latex3

I'd like to add TeX4ht support for my package, which is written in LaTeX3.

Is it safe to switch `\ExplSyntaxOn` inside a .4ht file? Should I switch it off at the end?

If it was NOT safe, how should I proceed to redefine (in classic syntax) a macro that has a LaTeX3 name (with underscores)

Comment: A short sample file would help us be more specific in our answers.

Comment: What @AndrewCashner says, without a [minimal (non)-working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) it's difficult to see what you mean, with the MWE, you'll likely find out what works and what does not ;)

Comment: Of course, I tested with a MWE. But my question was not "Does it work or not?". My question was "Is it safe?", meaning "Is it a good idea to do so? Or does it have side effects that could break things in complex scenarios?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` are smart commands and restore catcodes of redefined characters to their previous values, so it is safe to use them even in `.4ht` files, where `:` has catcode of `letter`. We can test it with following package, `hello.sty`:

```
\RequirePackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand\hello {m}{
  \hello:n{#1}
}

\cs_new:Npn \hello:n #1{hello\ LaTeX3:\ #1}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\sample{old sample}
```

two document commands `\hello` and `\sample` are defined, one using `LaTeX3` features, the second with plain `\def`, just to show that it works, which we can test with this configuration file, `hello.4ht`:

```
\NewConfigure{hello}{2}

\NewConfigure{sample}{2}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set:Npn \hello:n #1{\a:hello hello\ tex4ht:\ #1\b:hello}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\Configure{hello}{\HCode{<span class="hello">}}{\HCode{</span>}}

\pend:def\sample{\a:sample}
\append:def\sample{\b:sample}
\Configure{sample}{\HCode{<span class="sample">}}{\HCode{</span>}}
```

`\hello` is redefined to print text "hello tex4ht:`and content of two hooks, which are later configured to insert`span`element with`class=hello`attribute. To show that`tex4ht`command works as usual,`\sample`is redefined as well,`\pend:def`and`\append:def` insert content at the beginning and at the end of the redefined macro.

Now we can show some test document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hello}
\begin{document}

\hello{world} and \sample
\end{document}
```

and result:

```
<!--l. 5--><p class="noindent" ><span class="hello">hello&#x00A0;tex4ht:&#x00A0;world</span> and <span class="sample">old sample</span></p>
```